# SharedPreferences not working in android 4.2 Jellybean

Tags: sharedpreferences

I am using sharedpreferences which working from android 2.2 and android 4.1.1. But , shared preferences stopped working in android 4.2.  I am using only android.content.SharedPreferences not preferenceactivity or preferencefragment.

Can anyone explain why it is not working and any alternative solution for this issue ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" Throwing exceptions? Not retrieving the right values? We need much more detail!